# Como funciona o gerenciamento de dependências/bibliotecas do React?

Tags: react

Olá, galera

Como funciona o gerenciamento de dependências/bibliotecas do React? Tem alguma página na documentação que fala sobre? Importar uma biblioteca que possui, em sua maioria, coisas que não vou usar (ou seja, que eu uso poucas coisas da biblioteca) deixa meu projeto mais pesado?

--

Explicando de forma mais detalhada e com exemplo:

Vamos supor que esteja usando [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com) no meu projeto. Essa biblioteca possui muitos elementos UI do Material Design. Mas eu só vou usar, por exemplo, os buttons e os cards.

O fato de eu estar usando apenas duas coisas de uma biblioteca que possui várias outros elementos é ruim pro desempenho do meu projeto? O React é inteligente o suficiente pra carregar pro meu projeto apenas o que vou usar? Ou seja, o React carrega, nessa situação, apenas os elementos que vou usar, ou ele carrega a lib toda?

---

DÚVIDA 2, MAS SEGUINDO O PENSAMENTO DO QUESTIONAMENTO ANTERIOR

No exemplo da importação de [icons do Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/style/icons/) existe diferença pro React na importação das seguintes formas:

```
import AccessAlarmIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarm';
import { AccessAlarm } from '@material-ui/icons';
```

---

Não sei se fui redundante ou claro o suficiente. Qualquer dúvida adicional, estou a disposição.

Answer (score 1):

Com relação à primeira dúvida. Sim, o React é "inteligente o suficiente" para carregar apenas os elementos que estão sendo importados.

Quanto à segunda dúvida. O primeiro exemplo vai importar o que estiver sendo exportado como "default" no arquivo "AccessAlarm.js" e será utilizada com o alias "AccessAlarmIcon". O segundo import irá procurá um export específico definido como "AccessAlarm" no caminho especificado.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, Cássio.

Achei essa matéria *[The Correct Way to Import Lodash Libraries - A Benchmark](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark)* na qual o autor faz um benchmark de importação com o Lodash. Também responde a minha dúvida. Vale a pena dar uma olhada.